# Open the Uart0 Serial Port on Intel Edison

Tags: serial, arduino-ide, edison

I'll preface this buy saying I am very new to working with Arduino boards or hardware in general.
I am attempting to follow a tutorial on instructables

http://www.instructables.com/id/PCBot/step4/Printer-test/

I have my board and printer wired up properly and I have git cloned the python thermal printer. My issue begins at this paragraph:

> Open the UART0 serial port
>   by default the GPIO's of the edison are disables.
>
> You can enable them by programming the edison via the Arduino IDE or by using the MRAA library available for several programming languages.
>
> To open enable the UART0 port, TX RX on the edison breakout board, open a Python shell in the thermal and write:
>
> import mraa
>
> x=mraa.Uart(0)

I opened a python shell and entered the `import mraa` lines and tried to run the `printertest.py`

I receive an error that says no module named serial. I am not sure where the issue is. I thought the Edison already had python serial installed. I did try to install it with `opkg install python-serial` but it didn't work. If my issue is with enabling the Uart0 port I am not sure how to go about doing it. I have the Arduino IDE installed but I have no idea how to go about enabling it via the Arduino IDE. The instructions are a bit vague in that paragraph.

*Update I have successfully installed pip and got pyserial installed. Now when I try to run the printertest.py I get an error `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyAMA0'` which I think is potentially caused by me not succesfully opening Uart0 port but I am not sure how to. I tried adding the import in a shell as well as adding it directly to the code via nano

Comment: did you try with pip?

Comment: I tried to install pip but I got an error.

Comment: I suggest you paste the opkg error. Just as you describe the problem right now, it's hard to say much, without logs. Same as with pip: show how it fails.

Comment: I just found out I need unofficial repos to install pip so i'll try that next

Comment: I followed this blog to install pip on the edison http://blog.salvius.org/2015/05/installing-pip-on-intel-edison.html ; however, when I try to install pyserial with pip it says -sh: pip: command not found

Comment: @IgorStoppa here is the error from just trying to use opkg `root@edison:~# opkg install python-serial
Unknown package 'python-serial'.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_conf_parse_file: Duplicate src declaration (all http://repo.opkg.net/edison/repo/all). Skipping.
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package python-serial.`

Comment: how about the full list of repositories? did you check if it's configured as in your example?

Comment: Another - painful, for sure - way to install it, is to modify the list of components and rebuild the image. But I'd keep it as really last resort, as it is likely to take easily a couple of hours straight, if not more.

Comment: @IgorStoppa I might have to try reflashing the newest image. I don't notice any errors adding official or unofficial repos. The pip installation appears to have no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issues and successfully connected this printer with the Compute Module. I solved the issue by changing the target of `/dev/ttyAMA0` to `/dev/ttyMFD1` as shown by http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/edison.html . This was the final step after I had installed pyserial.